# Python lxml get elements with nesting predictates

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, lxml

Having the following xml structure:

[image]

I want to get the `b` elements that have nested `c` elements with the text '1'.

Is there a way to get them using XPath syntax?

After I got an the element of `a`, I tried this:

`aElementObject.xpath("b[//c[text()='1']")` without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider using text for the xml example so we can copy/paste and try it out.

Comment: Just a typo. It should be "b[//c/text()='1']"

Comment: ...oops, just tried it. You don't want // as that searches from root. So `b[c/text()='1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath you are looking for is

```
b[c='1']
```

So the whole expression could look like

```
aElementObject.xpath("b[c='1']")
```

These expressions do select all `b` children of an element which has a `c` child with the value of `1`.

Comment: It gives me all the b elements from the root, I want only the elements for my current `a` element

Comment: Not sure that works, I have many `a` elements in my file. I'm iterating them and in each one wants to get all it's inner fitting `b`. Sorry if that was not clear

Answer (score 0):

Besides a simple typo, it looks like you want to look for all descendants of the `b` elements. That would be

```
b[descendant::c/text()='1']
```